# How to know I get a inexistent or dead actor

Tags: java, akka, actor

I was trying to migrate my code from Akka 2.0 to 2.3.
I got several problems.

```
public synchronized ActorRef getActor(Class<? extends UntypedActor> clsActor, String sID)
{
    String sName = clsActor.getName() + "-" + sID;
    ActorRef actor = m_actorSystem.actorFor("user/" + sName);
    if (actor.isTerminated())
        actor = m_actorSystem.actorOf(new Props(clsActor), sName);
    return actor;
}
```

This is a actor dispatcher. If this actor dead or not exist, it would create a new actor.

But in Akka 2.3, isTerminated() is deprecated.

```
public ActorRef getActor(Class<? extends UntypedActor> clsActor, int id)
{
    String sName = clsActor.getName() + "-" + id;
    ActorRef actor = m_actorSystem.actorSelection("user/" + sName).anchor();
    return actor;
}
```

I get a actor back, but I don't know whether it is alive, until I send a message out.
Surely, it not worked.

How to fix this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into using ActorSelection similar to what you have already, but you need to call resolveOne on it which looks it up and returns a Future. You can then evaluate the result.

```
public ActorRef getActor(Class<? extends UntypedActor> clsActor, int id)
{
    String sName = clsActor.getName() + "-" + id;
    ActorSelection sel = m_actorSystem.actorSelection("user/" + sName);
    Timeout timeout = new Timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Future<ActorRef> fut = sel.resolveOne(timeout);
    ActorRef actor= Await.result(fut, timeout.duration());

    return actor;
}
```

If the actor doesn't exist an `ActorNotFound` exception will be thrown so you should decide where you want to handle this.

Also, be aware of the blocking nature of the Await.result call.